# Как мне создать SRV cloudflare запись для сайта?

Tags: http, site, cloudflare

Мне необходимо чтобы когда пользователь заходит на aa.example.com его перебрасывало на srv.exampla.com:12345

для этого я думаю что могу использовать srv запись cloudflare, когда в качестве сервиса я пишу "_http" оно не работает что я делаю не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: SRV-записи не используются в протоколе HTTP, поэтому сделать так вы не сможете

Comment: может есть другой способ для решения моей проблемы?